# Create a new tag from attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, tags

I need an xsl transformation that, given inputs like (with variable number of columns and rows)

```
<row>
<column inum="1">...</column>
<column inum="2">...</column>
[...]
</row>
<row>
[...]
```

gives back a structure like

```
<row>
<column_1>...</column_1>
<column_2>...</column_2>
[...]
</row>
<row>
[...]
```

I've seen many answers, but all about copying/modifying attributes, not using them to create new tags. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a rather trivial exercise:

```
<xsl:template match="column">
    <xsl:element name="column_{@inum}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I t works fine, thank you! 

P.S.: do you know a version using a progressive also? Without tags in input

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Did you perhaps mean `<xsl:element name="column_{position()}">`?

Comment: It doesn't works...

Comment: Again, I am afraid I don't know what you mean. If necessary, post a new question with your new requirement and explain in detail.