# New tag by position from xsl

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I have a slightly different question, comparing to [this previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298484/create-a-new-tag-from-attribute):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <importoTotaleCommissioni>
    <row>
        <column>5</column>
        <column>6</column>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column>5</column>
        <column>6</column>
        <column>7</column>
        <column>8</column>
    </row>
</importoTotaleCommissioni>
```

I have to create an output, by xsl, with tags named positionally, for example

```
<importoTotaleCommissioni>
    <row>
        <column_1>5</column_1>
        <column_2>6</column_2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column_1>5</column_1>
        <column_2>6</column_2>
        <column_3>7</column_3>
        <column_4>8</column_4>
    </row>
</importoTotaleCommissioni>
```

The columns enumeration must restart at every row. I have tried using

```
<xsl:template match="column">
    <xsl:element name="column_{position()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

... but it gives me wrong enumaration. How can I correct this?

Comment: You can see your code (which I have suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298484/create-a-new-tag-from-attribute#comment132869614_75298589)) working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyho7D.

Comment: you suggested too to open a new question :)

Comment: I suggested you post a new question and explain in detail. Even now the problem you claim cannot be reproduced using your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use this template instead :

```
<xsl:template match="column">
  <xsl:element name="column_{count(preceding-sibling::column)+1}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```