# Multiple manipulations on column/row tags of xml by xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have furterly elaborated [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75362156/new-tag-by-position-from-xsl). I must take the same input:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <importoTotaleCommissioni>
    <row>
        <column>5</column>
        <column>6</column>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column>5</column>
        <column>6</column>
        <column>7</column>
        <column>8</column>
    </row>
</importoTotaleCommissioni>
```

But the output to be obtained is slightly different:

```
<importoTotaleCommissioni>
    <row>
        <fascia>custom text for row 1</fascia>
        <column_1>5</column_1>
        <column_2>6</column_2>
        <column_3>undefined</column_3>
        <column_4>undefined</column_4>
        <column_5>undefined</column_5>
        <column_6>undefined</column_6>
    </row>
    <row>
        <fascia>another custom text for row 2</fascia>
        <column_1>5</column_1>
        <column_2>6</column_2>
        <column_3>7</column_3>
        <column_4>8</column_4>
        <column_5>undefined</column_5>
        <column_6>undefined</column_6>
    </row>
</importoTotaleCommissioni>
```

The conditions are:

- I can have an indefinite number of rows
- I can have maximum 6 column in one row
- If there are less columns than 6, other must be defined and filled with "undefined"
- Any row have a custom value for "fascia" that I know, and I must insert positionally for each row

I have tried to see many example of for-each, variables and the use of function count(), but I can't combine these in xsl to obtain the result.

Comment: Well how do you imagine 'Any row have a custom value for "fascia" that I know, and I must insert positionally for each row' to happen in the context of programming with XSLT? How do you want to provide that data, as a parameter or as a secondary input document? Which version of XSLT or which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved with this

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="importoTotaleCommissioni">
    <importoTotaleCommissioni>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
    </importoTotaleCommissioni>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <row>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                <xsl:call-template name="fascia">
                    <xsl:with-param name="da" select="'xxx'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="a" select="'yyy€'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="position()=2">
                <xsl:call-template name="fascia">
                    <xsl:with-param name="da" select="'aaa€'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="a" select="'bbb€'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="position()=3">
                <xsl:call-template name="fascia">
                    <xsl:with-param name="da" select="'ccc€'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="a" select="'ddd€'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="position()=4">
                <xsl:call-template name="fascia">
                    <xsl:with-param name="da" select="'eee€'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="a" select="'fff€'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="position()=5">
                <xsl:call-template name="fascia">
                    <xsl:with-param name="da" select="'ggg€'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="a" select="'hhh€'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="position()=6">
                <xsl:call-template name="fascia">
                    <xsl:with-param name="da" select="'iii€'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="a" select="'lll€'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="column"/>

        <xsl:if test="count(./column)&lt;6">
            <xsl:call-template name="missing_columns">
                <xsl:with-param name="remaining" select="6-count(./column)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="fascia">
    <xsl:param name="da"/>
    <xsl:param name="a"/>
    <fascia>da
        <xsl:value-of select='$da'/> a
        <xsl:value-of select='$a'/>
    </fascia>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="column">
    <xsl:element name="column_{position()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="missing_columns">
    <xsl:param name="remaining"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$remaining > 0">
            <xsl:element name="column_{7-$remaining}">
                non previsto
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:call-template name="missing_columns">
                <xsl:with-param name="remaining" select="$remaining - 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise/>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: And what if you have more than 6 rows???

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. You said you "can have an indefinite number of rows". But you have only 6 `da` and `a` value pairs that you assign to the first 6 rows. What should be the value of `fascia` for rows #7 and up?